# Import SVG in MS Word for Mac with current version, viewing with older version

Tags: microsoft-word, svg

I have some SVG figures and I find that MS Word for Mac, version 16.16.10 (copyright 2018), can import SVG successfully. So far, so good.

Are older versions of MS Word, for any platform, able to view the document which contains the imported SVG? Or is it perhaps necessary to have an SVG-enabled version of MS Word?

I guess at the heart of it is whether MS Word is converting SVG to a non-SVG format upon import. I don't know anything about that, although if anyone knows, I would be interested to hear.

The main problem I want to avoid is that if I create a document which looks correct to me, and the then someone working with an older version of MS Word can't view the images correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an SVG formatted image is inserted into a document a PNG version is automatically made and also stored in the document. This PNG image is used by prior versions of Word, such as Word for the Mac 2011, that don't have the ability to insert SVG images.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Rich, I appreciate it. I have been working with SVG in my document and other people I send it to seem to be able to view it, so that's great. I know a lot depends on variables which I can't control (mostly what system + version of Word people are using) but anyway it seems to be working okay so I'm good to go for the moment.